# How to delete all files with lftp except for cgi-bin and .ftpquota

Tags: gitlab-ci, lftp

I'm setting up a new ci/cd pipeline on gitlab. For the deployment I have to run `npm run build` and then copy the `dist/` folder to the webserver via ftp (with lftp). To ensure a clean deployment the script should remove all files except the folder `cgi-bin` and the file `.ftpquota` on the webserver first and then copy the files.

I've researched through the web and haven't found a suitable solution. With the flag `--delete`, lftp deletes all files.

Thats my script so far:

```
- lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $HOST; mirror -Rnev dist/ ./ --ignore-time --delete --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
```

My current script removes all files, but I want it to remove everything except the `cgi-bin` folder and the `.ftpquota` file.

Comment: Check this answer -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138213/153843

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119458/lftp-mirror-to-remote-except-particular-file-present-on-remote) you should add the `-x` option:

Please check it